# Handle with overflowing memory in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory-management, encoding

I have a problem about overflowing memory in Matlab. I am working in channel coding using Ludy code. The encoding symbol `y` is created as following

```
y=x*G
```

where `G` is matrix *n*-by-*m* and `x` is input symbol that size *1*-by-*n*

My problem is that I want to work with number of input symbols is large. Hence, I must allocate a G matrix that its size is very large. However, it occurs overflow memory problem. I am using Matlab 2012a to do it. Could you suggest to me some method to resolve my problem

For example my `G` matrix is *40000*-by-*60000* 
This is my code

```
function G = gen_matrix(n,m)
    G = zeros(n,m);
    for i=1:m
        d=randi(n/2);
        column = [ones(1,d) zeros(1,n-d)];
        column = column(randperm(n));
        G(:,i) = column';
    end
end
```

This is my memory information

```
[userview systemview] = memory;

systemview.VirtualAddressSpace

ans = 

    Available: 1.4074e+14
        Total: 1.4074e+14
```

Comment: Have you read: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html? Also are your matrices suitable candidates to be [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) (i.e. contain a lot of zeros)

Comment: Well, do it otherwise (see @Dan 's answers) or buy more RAM ;)

Comment: @AnderBiguri more RAM might not help if yu don't read those articles. Matlab (32bit) by default only lets you access 2GB of RAM no matter how much you have.

Comment: @user8264 What OS are you using and is it 32 or 64 bit? Is your Matlab 32 or 64 bit? Upgrading might help...

Comment: @Dan Definetly. Memory issues are way comples than "buy more RAM", I know. But unless the OP nows that vector will be his/her upper boundary in memory, then he needs to find another way of doing it.

Comment: Thank all, sorry because I have tested my code with 40000 by 60000 and my computer is crashed. I must turn off it. I known one option that is upgrade matlab to 64 bit.Currently, I am using this version, however, it cannot resolve this problem and please see my update code. Please let me know any way to resolve that problem without upgrade memory or matlab version, if it is possible.

Comment: @user8264 well looks like you have lots of zeros in `G` so first thing to try is `sparse`... as already mentioned. Also once again have you read through the links I posted which explain multiple possibilities such as block processing or unlocking more OS RAM

Comment: @Dan: Can sparse matrix handle with my G matrix? Because each column in G matrix has at least one value equals 1. BTW, I am reading the block and unblocking memory. Can you try to modify my code to sparse matrix?

Comment: Did you read the `sparse` docs on creating a `sparse` matrix? Just try `G = sparse(zeros(n,m))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix:

```
function G = gen_matrix(n,m)
    G = sparse(zeros(n,m));
    for i=1:m
        d=randi(n/2);
        column = [ones(1,d) sparse(zeros(1,n-d))];
        column = column(randperm(n));
        G(:,i) = column';
    end
end
```